# Show song with typed letter

Tags: php, html, database

I'm making a search form with suggestions from database. All is going good but the problem is when I type "t" it shows the song with `t` likewise shows the song with `s` letter as well here is my code:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if($_POST) {
    $q = $_POST['searchword'];

    $sql_res=mysql_query("select * from vass_songs");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res)) {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $title=$row['title'];
        $img=$row['img'];
        $album_id=$row['album_id'];
        $re_title='<b>'.$q.'</b>';
?>
        <div class="suggestion_box" align="left">
            <a href="/song/<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <img src="/static/albums/<?php echo $id; ?   >_small.jpg");">
                </div><?php echo $title; ?><br/>
                <span style="font-size:9px; color:#999999"><?php echo $country; ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
<?php
    }
} else {

}
?>
```

Comment: You don't appear to filter based on the search word at all?

Comment: SELECT * FROM vass_songs WHERE title LIKE '%$q%' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['searchword'])) {
    $q = $_POST['searchword'];

    $sql_res=mysql_query("
        SELECT *
        FROM vass_songs
        WHERE title LIKE '%$q%'
    ");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res)) {
        $id     = $row['id'];
        $title  = $row['title'];
        $img    = $row['img'];
        $album_id = $row['album_id'];
        $re_title = "<b>{$q}</b>";

        ?>
        <div class="suggestion_box" align="left">
            <a href="/song/<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <img src="/static/albums/<?php echo $id; ?>_small.jpg");">
                <div><?php echo $title; ?></div><br/>
                <span style="font-size:9px; color:#999999">
                    <?php echo $country; ?>
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
} else {

}
?>
```

Comment: how do i close suggestion box when someone clicks on the song name and he will be redirected to the song?

Comment: you can do it using javascript/jquery.. just put `onclick` on the link and have a callback function in javascript that will do the stuff.